# Append mth and nth columns of a file with the columns of another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have 2 files having different number of columns and with huge number of rows:

```
bash-3.00$ cat fileA 
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
q,w,,,,y,u,,
a,z,,,,q,n,,
.........................
z,p,,,,w,e,,
```

PS1: a1 - a9 are the headers separated by comma (,). 
PS2: dot signs (.) means that there are many lines between the two lines

```
bash-3.00$ cat fileB 
b1      b2
f       t
a       p
m       n
..........      
m       y
t       o
```

PS: b1 - b2 are the headers and separated by space.

I want to append the a2 and a6 columns of fileA to the contents of b1 and b2 columns. That is, a2 column will be appended to the b1 column; a6 column will be appended to the b2 column.

So, the output file would be as follows:

```
bash-3.00$ cat output 
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
q,w,,,,y,u,,
a,z,,,,q,n,,
.........................       
z,p,,,,w,e,,
,f,,,,t,,,
,a,,,,p,,,
,m,,,,n,,,
.........................
,m,,,,y,,,
,t,,,,o,,,
```

How can I do that by a simple awk command?

Comment: Can you please post terminal output as `formatted text`, not as pictures?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk 'FNR == NR { print ; next ; } 
     NR > FNR && FNR > 1 { 
          split($0,A) ; 
          printf ",%s,,,,%s,,,\n",A[1],A[2] ;  }' f1 f2
```

(can be in one line, I break it to be more readable)

where

- `FNR == NR { print ; next ; }`  copy lines from first file
- `NR > FNR && FNR > 1` select line from second file without header
- `split($0,A) ;`  put two var in an array (`A`)
- `printf ",%s,,,,%s,,,\n",A[1],A[2] ;` and print

## edit

tested with f1

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
q,w,,,,y,u,,
a,z,,,,q,n,,
.........................
z,p,,,,w,e,,
```

and f2

```
b1  b2
f   t
a   p
m   n
m   y
t   o
```

run :

```
awk 'FNR == NR { print ; next ; } NR > FNR && FNR> 1 { split($0,A) ; printf ",%s,,,,%s,,,\n",A[1],A[2] ;  }' f1 f2
```

result:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
q,w,,,,y,u,,
a,z,,,,q,n,,
.........................
z,p,,,,w,e,,
,f,,,,t,,,
,a,,,,p,,,
,m,,,,n,,,
,m,,,,y,,,
,t,,,,o,,,
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it did not help. The output file seems to be empty:
bash-3.00$ awk 'FNR == NR { print ; next ; } 
>      NR > FNR && FNR > 1 { 
>           split($0,A) ; 
>           printf ",%s,,,,%s,,,\n",A[1],A[2] ;  }' fileA fileB > output
bash-3.00$ cat output 
bash-3.00$

Comment: @Murat that's not what he told you to run. Make sure you copy/paste the solution directly into the terminal. Running what you show in your comment should have produced error messages.

Comment: edited to add the one line solution.

Comment: @Archemar why are you splitting `$0`? awk already does that for you; also, there's no need for `NR > FNR`, the `next` does that already. See the version in my answer.

Comment: @terdon true, as per spliting $0 : I was mislead by commas, and FNR is quiet new in awk.

Comment: FNR is new? Are you sure? I've seen it for years. In any case, you're already using it, I'm just saying that the `NR>FNR` is not needed since you already have `FNR==NR{...; next}`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is to i) append the contents of file1 to file2 and ii) change the format of file2 to match that of file one. That is not what your question is actually asking for but it's what you show in your output. If I misunderstood, please edit your question and clarify.

So, to do that, you could simply do:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf ",%s,,,,%s,,,\n",$1,$2}' file2 >> file1
```

That will make `file1` the output file. If you want to keep `file1`, you could do:

```
( cat file1; awk 'NR>1{printf ",%s,,,,%s,,,\n",$1,$2}' file2 ) > out
```

Or, you could do the whole thing in `awk` (this is just a simplified version of Archemar's solution):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{print; next} FNR>1{printf ",%s,,,,%s,,,\n",$1,$2}' file1 file2 > out
```